# How to install Windows Server 2003 on HP Proliant DL360 G4

Tags: windows-server-2003, hp, hp-proliant

I have an HP Proliant DL360 G4, with the 5 working SCSI drives and one broken. I would like to install Windows Server 2003 and have an .iso installation disk.

When it try to boot, it starts Caldera Dr-DOS and hangs on `ntfsread.exe`. Nothing happens.

I've tried to make a bootable USB, but it doesn't recognize the usb.

How can I start the installation?

Comment: Are you using a Windows Server 2003 installation CD? Are you invoking the boot menu or the boot from CD option?

Comment: i've dowloaded an iso, and burned that on a cd, and cd is 1st boot option

Answer (score 4):

Let's clarify. You likely have a [ProLiant DL380 G4](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetDocument.aspx?docname=c04283181) server, not a DL360 G4. The DL360 G4 only has *two* drive bays...

[image]

You need to clear the Smart Array RAID controller's configuration before you attempt to install an operating system.

Please press `F8` during the server's POST process to enter the RAID controller's BIOS configuration utility (also known as the Option ROM Configuration for Arrays- ORCA). Do not include the "broken" drive in your configuration. Remove it from the server. You won't be able to build a new array with it. HP's [manual for Smart Array controllers](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.BINARYPORTLET/public/kb/docDisplay/resource.process/?spf_p.tpst=kbDocDisplay_ws_BI&spf_p.rid_kbDocDisplay=docDisplayResURL&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&spf_p.rst_kbDocDisplay=wsrp-resourceState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c00729544-15%257CdocLocale%253D&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) is here.

Create and save the array config, then proceed with the Windows installation as normal.

Comment: Y2020 - still useful.